# A RewriteRule for all VirtualHosts on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

After `a2enmod rewrite`, I wrote the file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/myspecific_rewrite.conf` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/test(/.*)?$ http://anothersite.tld/test$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^/test2(/.*)?$ http://anothersite2.tld/test [R]
```

Then I `a2enconf myspecific_rewrite` and the correct symbolic link is created in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`.

The problem is that this conf doesn't work : the rewrite is not active.

I want that rewrite to be active for all my virtual hosts. This file I wrote defines `RewriteRule`s outside of a `<VirtualHost>`... is there a way to make it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `include` in every VirtualHost directive pointing to the file.

Source for the info: [SO comment by Jeremy Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344588/how-can-i-implement-a-global-rewritecond-rewriterule-in-apache-that-applies-to)

alternative you can use

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteOptions Inherit

on every VirtualHost

Source: same question and [Apache Docs for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Didn't know `RewriteOptions Inherit`. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I finally did : using [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)'s `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` directives.

Here is my conf file :

```
Redirect permanent /test http://anothersite.tld/test
RedirectMatch permanent ^/test2(/.*)?$ http://anothersite2.tld/test
```

Advantage : I don't need mod_rewrite anymore.